# Setting up a tableviewcontroller with multiple sections and buttons

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I would like to know how to develop an IOS Table View Controller with multiple sections.

For example attached is a screenshot from DrawSomething account page. They have different headings like account settings, password, then some buttons below.

Would this be setup as one UITableViewController then setup image backgrounds for the headers and customized cells for each table cell, or would this be setup using multiple different view controllers all within one main view controller?

Further to this, could this be setup and designed using a NIB or would it be alot easier using code to generate this. I understand that it the choice of the developer and your opinion but in common practice if it is possible to design (as such) within the NIB it would be easier. Although designing a table view layout in NIB does not appear to be possible...

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For something like this, since there's nothing really dynamic about the content, I would use a UIScrollView and just place the various elements on it directly.

Comment: When you say place the various items on the UIScrollView would that be a UITableView as a sub view to the scroll?

Comment: No, I wouldn't use any kind of table view.  It's overkill for this.  Just add the items you want right onto the scrollview.

Comment: Do you mean add these as imageviews for the table styled layout, with the uitextfields on the scroll view too

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like each "section" of that table is actually a custom cell.  The "heading" of the cell is just a label with textFields place in it etc...

Get a UIImageView to back the cells and you're good to go.

I've done stuff very similar to this using Interface Builder.

Make each cell use a different reuse Identifier so that when you load the table you know which cell is which.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example links/videos/tutorials of how to achieve this please?

Comment: Sorry I don't I just messed around with the TableView inside Interface Builder. You know how to create a custom cell within a TableView (I guess) well that is just the same, using labels to position text etc... Well this is exactly like that.  Use labels to place the text where you want, UITextFields to put those where you want, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table view with multiple sections. You need to create custom cells for headings and the contents.