# Having a scroll view within a scroll view? Multiple tables on a page?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm getting a bunch of error messages as I try to implement what I have in mind and I've tried a few different ideas but nothing seems to be coming together as easy as I hoped.

Is it possible to have multiple sections in a single view? [Setting up a tableviewcontroller with multiple sections and buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12844859/setting-up-a-tableviewcontroller-with-multiple-sections-and-buttons) I was reading this and couldn't get a better idea, but the picture pretty much sums up what I am trying to accomplish.

I thought I could use one view controller with multiple scroll views (2) on the same view. Inside those scroll views each contains a table.

The error message I keep getting: 
[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "XHr-P5-Pad-view-NlR-zW-pcQ" nib but didn't get a UITableView.' I'm assuming it cant generate the table view inside the scroll view?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or if there is a easier way to implement having two different tabled sections (maybe even a button also) on the same view? Pretty new to xcode

Thanks

Comment: If A scroll view contains A table view, then you don't need the scrollview. Just use a tableView, or multiples.

Comment: What if I want to have two tables on one view, but each of those tables would contain more rows than space. Thats why i assumed I needed two scroll views inside a view controller. Are you saying have two static tables on one view controller and just forget the scroll in general?

Comment: You can have two table views on one view controller. For example, size the top table view to fill the upper half of the screen and the lower table view to fill the lower half of the screen. Each table view can have as many sections/rows as they need. The two would scroll independently. No scroll views required.

Answer (score 0):

The best and safest way to go about your plan is to use Container Views. From the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html):

> "Container view controllers are a critical part of iOS app design.
>   They allow you to decompose your app into smaller and simpler parts,
>   each controlled by a view controller dedicated to that task.
>   Containers allow these view controllers to work together to present a
>   seamless interface."

This way you can have tons of different things on the same screen and still have your ode looking neat.

More:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7758892/2535467